# Jquery Iframe Popup

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to open a link in a iframe popup when somebody click on a image, this is the code -

```
<div class="photo-container">
    <a href="<?php echo $offer_link1 ?>">
        <img src="./images/im12.png" height="100" width="100">
    </a>
</div>
```

How can i open the link in a iframe popup?

The URL is - http://beflirty.net/lp1/signup12.php

Thanks.

Comment: `<a target="_blank|_self|_parent|_top|framename">`

Comment: and what is a iframe popup for you?

Answer (score 7):

try this

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
 $(document).ready(function (e) {
 $("framediv").hide();
    $("#link1").click(
function (e) {

$("#framediv").css({'display':'block'});
});
 });

</script>


<div class="photo-container">
 <a name="link1" href="<?php echo $offer_link1 ?> " target="frame1">
     <img src="./images/im12.png" height="100" width="100">
 </a>
</div>

<div id="framediv">
 <iframe height="900px" width="1100px"  name="frame1" border="0px"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Great its working :)
but how can i make a box around the the popup , and make the rest of the page darker ?

Comment: I tried to use - data-theme=data-overlay-theme and data-transition=flip but its didn't work where i should place it so it would work?